# Интерактивная карта

Tags: html, javascript, css

Подскажите, в чём проблема.

Делаю карту для сайта, в отдельном [файле](http://visokopilsk-vlada.ks.ua/map.html) всё работает хорошо, а когда подключаю на [страницу](http://visokopilsk-vlada.ks.ua/), то выделение вылазит в конце страницы. При наведении мышки на село, оно меняет цвет, а на странице выделение появляется внизу.

Answer (score 1):

В первом примере скрипт задает значение position:absolute и высчитывает
 top и left элементу. А на сайте он просто показывает его, посмотрите какой-то скрипт  забыли подключить.

Comment: на сайт первый файл подключается через include, подключено всё что нужно

Comment: подключите скрипты в head как в примере

Comment: уже пробовал проблема в другом

Comment: конечно вынести в iframe, тоже решение, но лучше разобраться в чем проблема, к тому же у меня в ие7 и 8 выскакивает ошибка и скрипт карты не работает, также не забудьте добавить frameborder="0", чтобы убрать бордеры в ие